# getValue from an XML having same attributes using Perl XMLDOM parser

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I am trying to get the value of 'TaxAmount' from the below XML which contains same tag name at different places.

From the below XML, I want to get the value of 'TaxAmount' as '7.2' under tag 'Order', but I'm always getting the 'TaxAmount' as '1.2' under tag 'OrderItem' in 'OrderItemList'.

Could any one help me on getting the value of 'TaxAmount' as '7.2'?

I tried many things from other similar questions, but not succeeded in any.

```
<Order>
  <CustomerID />
  <IsCustomerCompany>false</IsCustomerCompany>
  <OrderTimezone />
  <OrderDescription />
  <OrderItemList>
    <OrderItem>
      <OrderItemID>1234</OrderItemID>
      <ItemCode />     
      <TaxAmount>6.0</TaxAmount>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
      <OrderItemID>1245</OrderItemID>
      <ItemCode />
      <TaxAmount>1.2</TaxAmount>
    </OrderItem>
  </OrderItemList>
  <Currency>USD</Currency>
  <Amount>120</Amount>
  <TaxAmount>7.2</TaxAmount>
</Order>
```

The piece of code I'm using is,

```
use XML::DOM;

$xml = XML::DOM::Parser->new->parse( $self->fullresponse )->getDocumentElement;
my $order_tag = $xml->tag('Order');
my $tax_amount =  $order_tag->getValue('TaxAmount');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, its typo error. modified my question.

Comment: You will need to show the code that you want help with

Comment: I'm trying,   my $tax_amount = $order_tag->getValue('TaxAmount');, where $order_tag is $xml->tag(''Order''); but still i'm getting value as '1.2'.

Comment: Please show your code *in context*. You haven't explained what modules you're using, amongst many other things

Comment: I'm not sure that code actually works: `Can't locate object method "tag" via package "XML::DOM::Element" `. Please can you update it with a working example?

Comment: Please show the code that  shows a `TaxAmount` of 1.2 instead of 7.2. The lines you have posted don't run at all

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for specific about the module you're using, but this will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new (  ) -> parse ( 'your_xml_file' );
print $twig -> root -> get_xpath ( "./TaxAmount",0 ) -> text;
```

Note that in this example, your "root" node is `Order` so looking for `Order` beneath that is probably what's tripping you up.

Comment: I can't change/include any other new CPAN modules in our code as our client follows a strict code review. Could you please help me with XML::DOM parser?

Comment: No - you haven't supplied enough information in your question to do that. The code you supplied doesn't even run.